# How to clean up textureCache A-frame at current version?

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe, hls.js

I'm working on a multi camera streaming application and I noticed memory usage keep increasing after switching cameras. I cleaning up on the hls.js side. But I did not see any ways to do that in a-frame.
I'm using 1.2.0

I only found old post recommending
`document.querySelector('a-scene').systems.material.textureCache` and run `.dispose()`

Which looks like worked on 0.3.0 version, but not since.

Is there a way to clean up textures or is this now happens automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afaik the `textureCache` is an object that keeps promises with loaded textures ([image](https://github.com/gftruj/aframe/blob/master/src/systems/material.js#L90), [video](https://github.com/gftruj/aframe/blob/master/src/systems/material.js#L172)).

There is a [`clearTextureCache`](https://github.com/gftruj/aframe/blob/master/src/systems/material.js#L38) function but it clears the object, without disposing the loaded textures.

I'd try iterating through the `textureCache`, grabbing the `THREE.Texture` objects and calling `.dispose()` on them. Then you can do `clearTextureCache()` to clean it up. In the below example - any click io the window will get the cached textures printed in the console:

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent("foo", {
    init: function() {
      window.addEventListener("click", e => {
        const textureCache = this.el.systems.material.textureCache;
        console.log("Textures in the cache:")
        for (let key in textureCache) {
          textureCache[key].then(val => console.log(val))
        }
      })
    }
  })
</script>
<a-scene foo>
  <a-image position="-1 1.6 -2" src="https://i.imgur.com/wjobVTN.jpeg"></a-image>
  <a-image position="1 1.6 -2" src="https://i.imgur.com/AD3MbBi.jpg"></a-image>
  <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
```